# Реализация синглтона через unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, singleton

Встретил несколько раз в проектном коде реализации синглтонов подобным образом:

```
class singleton {
public:

    static singleton& get() 
    {
        std::call_once(m_flag, []()
        {
            m_instance.reset(new singleton());
        });
        return *m_instance.get();
    }

    virtual ~singleton() {}

private:

    static std::unique_ptr<singleton> m_instance;
    static std::once_flag m_flag;

    singleton() {}
    singleton(const singleton& other) = delete;
    singleton& operator=(const singleton& rhs) = delete;
};

std::unique_ptr<singleton>  singleton::m_instance = nullptr;
std::once_flag              singleton::m_flag;
```

Вопрос мой относительно использования `std::unique_ptr` в этой реализации. Зачем могло потребоваться это использовать? Чтобы явно вызывать деструктор во время работы? А если потребуется экземпляр синглтона заново создать, то придется заново конструировать его, а это может быть недешево. Почему бы просто не использовать реализацию Майерса типа:

```
class Singleton
{
  public:
    static Singleton& Instance()
    {
        // согласно стандарту, этот код lazy-init и потокобезопасный
        static Singleton s;
        return s;
    }

  private:
    Singleton() { ... }
    ~Singleton() { ... }

    Singleton(Singleton const&);
    Singleton& operator= (Singleton const&);
};
```

Не вижу никаких причин, кроме как любви к `->`

Comment: @VTT не тот пример немного, деструктор публичный и там реализация `std::unique_ptr` , не тот код скопировал.

Comment: Деструктор объекта все равно вызвать не получится. Этот код страдает от того же дефекта, что и синглетон меерса - нет контроля над временем жизни синглетона. Потом написавшие этот код программисыты бегут жаловаться, что синглетоны являются антипаттерном и не дают им нормально тестировать код... Контроль времени жизни и количества одновременно сущесвующих экземпляров объекта не являются задачами синглетона (хотя обычно сопутствуют друг другу).

Comment: Кажется понял. А что, есть реализация синглтона с контролем времени жизни? Что-то не слышал о такой(

Comment: Конечно есть, обычно они содержат optional_reference / указатель на объект (время жизни которого контролирует кто-то еще). И методы для получения / установки экземпляра.

Comment: Тут 2 варианта: либо человек, который писал этот код не в курсе всех изменений в C++11, либо этот код писался под MSVS 2010, который не поддерживал потокобезопасную инициализацию статического объекта.